# button onclick, but button isn't clickable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to follow a video, but the button isn't working. I cannot press the button. How do I fix my code?

My code

```js
function increment() {
  console.log("added");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Amount:</h1>
  <h2 id="count-el">0</h2>

  <button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">INCREMENT</button>
  <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm not certain where to go from here

Comment: It looks like it's working to me .. I get the console saying "added"

Comment: ah, I wasn't looking at the terminal -_- ty ty.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems running fine, I just added the increment function. You'll see the button work. :)

```js
function increment() {
  document.getElementById("count-el").innerHTML = eval(document.getElementById("count-el").innerHTML) + 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Amount:</h1>
  <h2 id="count-el">0</h2>

  <button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">INCREMENT</button>
  <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```